# Xdocument - how to convert non-html safe characters

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a "title" attribute inside elements of my UTF-8 xml, e.g.

```
<tag title="This is some test with special chars §£" />
```

as I want the content of this attribute to be printed directly in an HTML page, I'm trying to have an output like:

```
<tag title="This is some test with special chars &#x00a7;&#x00a3;" />
```

The code fragment where I add there attribute looks like this:

```
new XElement( "tag",
    new XAttribute( "title" , title)
);
```

Characters such as & and " are escaped, but §£ are not - as they're valid utf-8 characters.
What should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UTF-8 characters are supported in HTML, if the page is declared as UTF-8.**

> You should always specify the encoding
>   used for an HTML or XML page. If you
>   don't, you risk that characters in
>   your content are incorrectly
>   interpreted. This is not just an issue
>   of human readability, increasingly
>   machines need to understand your data
>   too. You should also check that you
>   are not specifying different encodings
>   in different places.

If the default encoding for the page is a character set with a smaller range, then it will not render all of the UTF-8 characters properly.  However, if the document is declared as UTF-8 they should display fine.

Rather than replacing characters with entity references, [you may need to explicitly declare the encoding of your page as UTF-8.](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations)

There are a variety of ways to do this:

- `<meta charset="UTF-8">`
- `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">`
- `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: any drawbacks? I'm thinking about IE/mobile devices compatibility. Also, which way would you recommend? I'd go for either of the meta tags, not the last as I suppose it requires XHTML

Comment: The preferred method depends on what you are creating (i.e. HTML 4, HTML 5, XHTML). HTML4 - Use a pragma directive at the top of the head element. `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">`. I don't know whether it would "hurt" to use both meta tags, to cover your bases.

Comment: this sounds very interesting, however from a quick testing it looks like at least ffox completely ignores the meta tag and goes straight to the `content-type` header encoding. I suppose I need to change that, no way to circumvent the header?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can manually decode those characters. I have used this before

```
 Dictionary<string, char> HTMLSymbolMap = new Dictionary<string, char>()
        {
            {"&#8211;",'–'},
            {"&#8212;",'—'},
            {"&#8216;",'‘'},
            {"&#8217;",'’'},
            {"&#8218;",'‚'},
            {"&#8220;",'“'},
            {"&#8221;",'”'},
            {"&#8226;",'•'},
            {"&#183;",'·'},
            {"&#8222;",'„'},                
            {"&#163;",'£'},
            {"&#167;",'§'},

        };

   public string CleanJunk(string docText)
    {


        foreach (var kv in HTMLSymbolMap)
        {
            docText = docText.Replace(kv.value.tostring(), kv.key);
        }

        return docText;

    }
```

Refer this [HTMLSymbol table](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) for more info